# What is a return type function

Tags: function, return, return-type

I am trying to understand the return type function but I really can't. For example in this code:

```
int add(int a, int b){
    result=a-(-b);
    return result;
}
```

I cant understand why it became return result and what is it for and what it do.I am new in c++ and Iwanted to become better in c++.

Comment: The `int` before `add` means the function `add` will return an integer when its done. So you do some calculation and the result is an integer. Now this function essential takes the integer `a` and `b` and calculate `a -(-b)` which essentially `a + b` and save it to the result variable. Then it will just return this value. It would be same if you would write in the function body only `return a - (-b);`. By the way that result must be declared else where globally it seems.

Comment: Also no such thing as "return type function". There are functions and they have return types, which declares what type of value will they resulting/returning when they invoked/called.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to give back an answer (value) to the other part of your program, which called this function.

Let's say you do something like:

```
print(add(2,4));
```

Your program would print the value: `6`

**Disclaimer**: not really sure if the syntax is correct, it's been over a decade since I last programmed in C++;